# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE does not work with jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

On Mac, with mysql client ( which does not use jdbc) when I execute this command, it works without any issue:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv'  REPLACE INTO TABLE transaction_details FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

this works with jdbc without any issue:(no REPLACE, so ignore duplicates)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv'  INTO TABLE transaction_details FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

When I execute the same command using jdbc, I see this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'our_rate' at row 1
```

I suspect I may have to add some options to jdbc url, but I am not sure what they are.
Any suggestion and help is appreciated.

I have data, that includes new and updates to existing records and hence I need to use REPLACE and I know why I am doing this way.

Comment: Yes, but it's not really sql is it? `LOAD INFILE` is a MySql admin command. Perhaps it could be *made* to work but probably better to do batch updates using the csv file as input to the `INSERT`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my ask is to why the same not working with jdbc with REPLACE in the query. And how to make it work.
I need to add 10M records and have 140 columns, LOAD works really faster.

Comment: Can you show us some data, and the table schema for a [mre]? (TBH I'm surprised `LOAD DATA` works at all via JDBC.)

Comment: (Also, the way the question is written, you are telling us that you have a command which works using JDBC and also does not work using JDBC... Which is a bit confusing - to me, anyway. I assume you mean "works without `REPLACE` but does not work with `REPLACE`".)

Comment: Your understanding is right andrewJames. I could insert 3M records, so works with JDBC.